# How can I patch small rectangular holes in plaster over brick?

Tags: walls, patch

I have recently had my split cycle air conditioner's indoor unit moved a few inches to a new position. The old installation position looks like this in the attached photo.

What is the most ideal and/or easiest solution to fill these holes?

The wall is a double brick wall.

[image]

Comment: Depends...are you talking about the rectangular hole in the middle of the pic, the round hole at the top left, or the small round holes scattered around?  Or AOTA?

Comment: rectangular ones

Comment: What's behind the hole?  Is there any ductwork, or piping?

Comment: I assume this is plaster and updated your title accordingly. Revise as needed so the community knows what we're dealing with. Also, while size is subjective, these aren't "large" holes by home improvement standards.

Comment: If it's a double brick wall, you'll need to start with patching the brick wall with cut bricks and mortar (or chisel out the mortar on partial bricks around the hole and mortar in a full brick)

Comment: seems the same as any other plaster repair. except you'll have to attach the patch to the hole differently.